# How to parse the content from a JSON file to a script of an offline website run on webview

Tags: javascript, html, json

How do I write a js that extract some selected contents from a json file to display on a local webview as a function of another app. But it seems like every method to parse the json that I got from Google didn't work.

My current html declaration:

```
<html>
   <body onload="onLoad()" scroll="no">
   </body>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
var JSON_FILE = "data.json";
function loadData {
    const fs  = require('fs');
    var allStrings;
    fs.readFile(JSON_FILE, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error reading file from disk");
        } else {
        // parse JSON string to JSON object
            allStrings = JSON.parse(fs.ReadFileSync(JSON_FILE));
        }
    })
}

function onLoad {
        loadData();
};

onLoad();
```

and it got this error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined*

I tried to add *"type="module""* to script declaration but it got this error:
*`Access to script at 'file:///C:/project/xxxxxx/html_document/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge.`*

And: *"Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad is not defined"*

I also tried this but it also didn't work:

```
var allString = JSON.parse(ReadFileSync(JSON_FILE));
```

got this error *Uncaught ReferenceError: ReadFileSync is not defined*

Comment: [fs is a NodeJS module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and not available in the browser. I'd suggest using a [file input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) or request the file from a server using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: I tried fetch but it returns NET error, understandable since it's an offline page and an offline json file. How do I use declare file input in the html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that it can't be done a web browser since reading files or fetch requires addition lib or JSNode which can't be done for a simple website.

But I found a workaround solution by instead of reading from a json file, I declare the json string in a separated js file:

```
const ALL_STRINGS = {...}
```

Probably not the best approach but it satisfied my requirement for a light, simple website.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code in main.js

```
var JSON_FILE = "data.json";

function loadData() {
    fetch(JSON_FILE)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("There has been a problem with your fetch operation:", error);
    });
}

function onLoad() {
    loadData();
}
```

// No need to call onLoad here since it's already being called on body load

Comment: It got these erros: Access to fetch at 'file:///C:/project/xxxxxx/html_document/data.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge.

main.js:169  GET file:///C:/project/xxxxxx/html_document/data.json net::ERR_FAILED